# MatLAB fsolve calculation

Tags: matlab

have a problem with MatLAB
How can I view the intermediate calculations for a given function? not only for the desired variable, but also for the equations included in the system for fsolve.
[fsolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqYJY.png) [first eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jUxF.png) [second eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7UVT.png) [fsolve system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmIzL.png)

```
function solve_syst ()
a_init = -2;
c = 6;
d = 8;
for i = 1:7
    b = i + 4;
syst_eq = @(a) syst_3 (a, b, c, d);
a_vih = fsolve (syst_eq, a_init);
a(i) = a_vih
end
```

first eq

```
function x1 = syst_1 (a, b) %first eq
x1 = a * 6 + 2 * b;
end
```

second eq

```
function x2 = syst_2 (c, d)%second eq
x2 = c * 4 - d * 2;
end
```

system for solve

```
function [prov, x1, x2] = syst_3 (a, b, c, d) %system for fsolve
x1 = syst_1 (a, b)
x2 = syst_2 (c, d)
prov = x1 - x2;
end
```

Comment: Don't put code as picture please

Comment: sorry, didnt know

Answer (score 0):

You may step through your program using the Matlab debugger. Just [set a breakpoint](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html) in your code where you want to see the intermediate results.
You can view the current content of your variables either in the workspace, or by typing their name in the console.
You can also navigate step by step onwards from your breakpoint through your code as explained [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).